# Datatable selectAll records even searched for particular one

Tags: jquery, .net, datatable

I am using Datatable to show agrid. There are `selectAll` options to select all records having a checkbox class.
My problem is when I search for a particular ID it filters across multiple pages then I go to `selectAll` and all records are selected even if they are hidden or disabled.

Here is my code:

```
oTableCompletedAppt = $('#consignmentnote').dataTable({
    "language": {
        "emptyTable": "-",
        "paginate": {
            "previous": "<",
            "next": ">"
        }
    },
    "searching": true,
    "lengthChange": true,
    "info": true,
    "ordering": true
});
```

This is `selectAll` jquery:

```
$("#selectAll").on("change", function () {
    debugger;
    if ($('#selectAll').is(":checked")) {
        oTableCompletedAppt.$("input[type='checkbox']").attr('checked', $(this.checked));
    } else {
        oTableCompletedAppt.$("input[type='checkbox']").attr('checked', false);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: Upon further review here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gyrocode/07Lrpqm7) with a full implementation and working example.
You'll have to do it in 4 steps:

1. Use [`columns.render`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) to add a checkbox to each row
2. Handle click on "Select all" control
3. Handle click on each checkbox
4. When submitting form iterate rows looking for checkboxes that have the attribute `checked` settled in the previous steps.

Original answer:
Why don't you use the [selectAll](https://datatables.net/reference/button/selectAll) button?
Then all you have to do to select filtered rows is:

```
{
    text: 'Select All',
    action: function () {
        table.rows({
            search: 'applied'
        }).select();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please show me where I need to use this code?

Comment: Check my edit, hope it helps you solve your issue.